# Google Maps Directions Service, How to wait for all requests to finish?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-react

I have a list of technicians that I need to get individual drive times between a certain location.  I have been using a script to do this within `Google Sheets` but I would rather do the computation within my web application instead.  There are of course a few issues here.  One is that I can't just make these requests within a for loop without having some sort of delay, or else I will get an `over_query_limit` error.  The other issue is that I want a way to let the user know that all requests have finished, and that is the part I'm stuck on.  I'm currently using the `google-maps-react` npm package to accomplish this.

Here is what I currently have:

```
TechDriveTimeTest(techs, kioskInfo){
        let result = []
        techs.forEach(tech => {
            if(tech.Address != "" && !tech.Notes.includes('Not')){
                result.push(tech);
            }
        })

        //console.log(result);

        let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        result.forEach((tech, index) => {
            let techAddress = tech.Address + " " + tech.City + " " + tech.State + " " + tech.Zip

            let req = {
                origin: techAddress,
                destination: 'some destination',
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }

            this.GetTime(index, req, directionsService);

        })
    }

    GetTime(i, req, service){
        setTimeout(function(){
            service.route(req, function(res, status){
                if(status == 'OK'){
                   let time = res.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text
                   console.log(time);
                }
            })
        }, (i+1) * 1000)
    }
```

This code works fine with delaying the requests so that I don't receive an error anymore, but it would be nice to know when all of the requests are finished so I can notify the user.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion to run the requests one at a time, here is an example:

```
function TechDriveTimeTest(techs, kioskInfo){
    techs = techs.filter(tech => tech.Address != "" && !tech.Notes.includes('Not'))
                 .map(tech => `${tech.Address} ${tech.City} ${tech.State} ${tech.Zip}`);

    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    recursion();
    function recursion() {
        const techAddress = techs.shift();
        directionsService.route({
            origin: techAddress,
            destination: 'some destination',
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(res, status){
            if(status == 'OK'){
               let time = res.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text
               console.log(time);
            }
            if (techs.length) {
                setTimeout(recursion, 1000);
            } else {
                console.log('DONE');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, the `recursion` removes the first element from the `techs` array and then, when the directions response comes in, if there are still elements in the `techs` array, the `recursion` function is called again.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a ```over_query_limit``` error?

Comment: @Michael No because `directionsService.route(..)` is called only after the response to the previous call comes in.

Comment: Ok I will give this a try.

Comment: I'm receiving that error when running this.  From what i've tested, google's api only allows you to make a single request within a second of the other one or else it displays the ```over_query_limit``` error.

Comment: @Michael I've edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: @Michael have you checked the latency of this API?

Comment: I ultimately used async/await in a for loop to run this.  The latency of the API seems to be enough to not trigger the query limits from Google.